# How im be able to do automated frontend tests?

Tags: html, automated-tests, frontend

I want to be able to do automated frontend testing. I want to reach that the test is able to open chrome, browse a specific website, tests my form, and collect the results of the test after submitting it.

I am new to this topic and I need a hint where I should start with. May someone can recommend me a way to start?

Comment: hmm what kind of system  requires functionality like that?  is that a school project? can you give an overview ?

Comment: this should help get you started https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at "[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)". This kind of software is a framework to make automated frontend tests, which does automate several tasks for you like do the task which you told us you want to do. It takes a bit of work to dig in, but if you did it once you should be easily able to write tests fast.

Also, there are two browser plugins which help you to create test cases for selenium:

[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/?src=search)

[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en)

Also, I can recommend this tutorial on youtube which helped me a lot.

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cobEbkTwbwY)

An automated test, in the end, can look like this:

[image]

The "Getting Started" section of the Selenium framework can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started/). Selenium is able to support various languages like:

Java/Kotlin, Python, C#, Ruby, JavaScript

You can found a list [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/).

Answer (score -2):

You can write a program in Python which uses Selenium and Chrome Web Driver. Here's the example of a Python program logging in on Social Media.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class SignInBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
            .send_keys(username)
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="password"]')\
            .send_keys(password)
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')\
            .click()

SignInBot('USERNAME', "PASSWORD")
```